# SMS: How to merge two groups with the same three individuals in both groups?

Tags: sms

For phone text (messages) groups, How to merge two groups with the same three individuals in both groups?

I have a google Pixel 5a phone, Android verson 14.  I don't know what other information would be needed to answer the question.

Comment: Which SMS app do you use, the  "Messages" app from Google?

Comment: Yes, I use "Messages" from Google.